# Storing a reference to the object in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist

Hey everyone i am trying to store the current reference to an arraylist "pl". **e.g. pl.add(this);**
for some  reason i only get the reference to the last item and none of the previous ones. The Loop does go through all three items tho.

Below is the code and out put i am getting. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong thank you for the help in advance.

```
       // variables
private String productType;
private String hyperLinkParam;
private ArrayList <ProductList> pl = new ArrayList<ProductList> ();

public ProductList() {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

       InputStream url = null;
        url = getClass().getResourceAsStream("inventory.xml");


        Document doc = db.parse(url);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        // loop through each item
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item"); //Returns a list of elements with the given tag name item
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++)
        {

                Element e = (Element) items.item(i);
                setHyperLinkParam(e.getAttribute("name").toString());
                setProductType(getTextValue(e,"productType"));
                System.out.print(e.getAttribute("name").toString());
                System.out.println(getTextValue(e,"productType"));

                pl.add(this);


         }

          for(int j=0; j < pl.size(); j++){
            System.out.print("getHyperLinkParam: " + pl.get(j).getHyperLinkParam());
            System.out.println("getProductType: " + pl.get(j).getProductType());
          }
```

Manufacture.java

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getProductList")
public ProductList getProductList() {
    try {
        ProductList productlist = new ProductList();
        if(productlist == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            return productlist;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
    <%
try {
org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.Manufacture_Service service = new org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.Manufacture_Service();
org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.Manufacture port = service.getManufacturePort();
// TODO process result here
org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.ProductList result = port.getProductList();
out.println("Result = "+result);

} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to guess the overall structure of ProductList and Product from what was posted here. The problem is that the list and the fields of a list element appear to be in the context of a single class, i.e., ProductList. This won't do - two classes are required.

```
// stores the data coming from a single Element ("item") of the document
class Product {
    private String productType;
    private String hyperLinkParam;
    public setHyperLinkParam( String hlp ){
        hyperLinkParam = hlp;
    }
    public setProductType( String pt ){
        productType = pt;
    }
}

// Container for a list of products from an inventory
class ProductList {
    private ArrayList <Product> pl = new ArrayList<Product> ();
    public ProductList() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream url = getClass().getResourceAsStream("inventory.xml");
        Document doc = db.parse(url);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        // loop through each item
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++){
            Element e = (Element) items.item(i);
            // create the single product from the current item
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.setHyperLinkParam( e.getAttribute("name").toString() );
            prod.setProductType( getTextValue( e, "productType") );
            // add it to the list
            pl.add( prod );
        }
    }

    void showList(){
        for( Product prod: pl ){
        System.out.print("getHyperLinkParam: " + prod.getHyperLinkParam());
            System.out.println("getProductType: " + prod.getProductType());
        }
    }
}
```

NB: Everything would be cleaner and clearer if the construction of a ProductList and of a Product would be in a Factory Class with Factory Methods makeProductList and makeProduct. A ProductList should have a method addProduct delegating the add to its pl member. And the knowledge of how to obtain a product list from the XML should be *there* and *not* in the constructor, and, similarly, the way the field values for a Product are obtained from an "item" element don't belong in the code of Product or ProductList.

Comment: The above code does display the different items, within the Productlist class i however cannot access the code within the JSP i am assuming i must not be returning the right object i titled the two new subsection above in the code Manufacture.java and index.jsp. Can you please assist me in the correction

Comment: shouldnt i be able to access it as productlist.product.getMethod() ?

Comment: @KSM I'm not acquainted with JSP, but if you need to get the contents of ProductList as a result (if that is what "out.println("Result = "+result)" is supposed to achieve) then you'll have to add a toString() method to ProductList: Use a StringBuilder and append all elements of pl.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
pl.add(this);
```

You're adding the same reference (`this`) again and again. The value of `this` *is* just a reference to the "current" object - and you're modifying the contents of that object in the loop.

In each iteration of the loop you should create a new, separate object, set the properties on *that* object, and then add a reference to that object to the list.

It's slightly odd that you'd be adding `this` to the list at all, to be honest - usually a method like this would be in some class which knew how to parse the XML, not an instance of the data item itself. It's not clear where `pl` is declared, but you should really consider the structure of your program.

Comment: I understand but the thing is how do i go about creating a new object in the code above ?? I modified my code to show where i declared the variables. Am i suppose to create a new pl object every time? Thank you for your help

Comment: @KSM: You call the constructor. `pl` isn't an object, it's a variable - and its value is a reference to the list, not the object you're trying to store in it. I'd expect to see (inside the loop) something like `Foo foo = new Foo(); foo.setFirstValue(...); foo.setSecondValue(...); pl.add(foo);`

Answer (score 2):

You keep adding the same object (this) to the list. Although you change the members, all references in the list keep referencing the same object.

You should create a new object and add that.

**See my other post**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ProductList obj=new ProductList();
// some work on this object and then store it in List
pl.add(obj);
```

It should work, because it will give you the fresh object

Comment: Ive added the New Coding Mentioned Above but it doesn't seem to work i get this output at org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.ProductList.<init>(ProductList.java:47)  And line 47 is where i create the new obj object

Comment: org.soen487.supplychain.manufacturer.ProductList.<init>(ProductList.java:47) And line 47 is where i create the new obj object

Comment: use obj.setHyperLinkParam(e.getAttribute("name").toString());
                obj.setProductType(getTextValue(e,"productType"));

Comment: if you looking above under new coding that's what i did but it does not seem to work

Comment: check what values are being stored inside the variables on obj reference, i think, this time values are going wrong.